# Pandas / Numpy - How do I get and compare the counts of every column with every column and write to csv?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I was trying to figure out how to compare the count of every data frame column to every data frame column. There can be over 300 columns, so there would be over 300 X 300 = over 90,000 comparisons. This is some sample data:

[image]

I was trying to figure out how many 'AGE' 55 were Female, how many 'AGE' 48 were male, how many Male were 'NP' D, etc.

This is part of the code I used:

```
df_search1 = pd.read_csv("file1.txt",sep='\t', 
dtype=str,engine='c',header=0,encoding='latin-1')

items = ['AGE','NP','GENDER']

headr = True
for item1 in items:
    headr = True
    for item2 in items:
        # appends
        df_search1[(df_search1['%s'%item1].notnull()) & (df_search1['%s'%item2].notnull())] 
        [['%s'%item2]].count().to_csv('search_out.txt',header=headr,sep='\t',mode='a')
        headr = False
```

The result I get are similar to this:

[image]

The results I was looking for were similar to this:
[image]

Where the first 'AGE', 'NP', 'GENDER' are on one row (just the counts with no column names); the second 'AGE', 'NP', 'GENDER' to be on the next row (just the counts with no column names); and the third 'AGE', 'NP', 'GENDER' to be on one row (just the counts with no column names).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A work around is to create a column that is populated with concatenating you other three column values and then apply the Regular expression query for the results. So your row "55 D Female" would be "55DFemale".

For e.g. If we use the same input table as yours, the regex would go as follows provided the order of column in concat is AGE+NP+GENDER

```
   Query                                  Regex
   1. how many 'AGE' 55 were Female    => (55)(.)(Female)
   2. how many 'AGE' 48 were male      => (48)(.)(Male)
   3. how many Male were 'NP' D        => ([0-9]{2})(D)(Male)
```

You can write program to create this Regex on the fly and then apply on the extra column and then pull the rows that results in regex match.